# How to deploy angular 9 site to IIS and access URL params

Tags: angular, iis, url-rewriting

I have an angular 9 site that I'd like to deploy to IIS.  I have set up a URL Rewrite rule as follows:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" appendQueryString="true" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This works fine for pages with a url pattern like https://example.com.com/login but it fails if an id is included in the URL like https://example.com/article/ce40ae27-f9d3-4efd-f28a-08d7d56db819 where the guid at the end is an ID.  IIS is just adding index.html to the end instead of interpreting the ID.

This particular URL can be though of as: https://example.com/article/{id: Guid}

What change do I need to make to my URL Rewrite to make this work?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: There's no IIS angular handler so IIS can't handle extensionless URL automatically. You may have to rewrite the GUID into querystring or somewhere to pass parameter.